# How to view the output of tf.train.batch()

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I have been following the ["RNNs in TensorFlow, a Practical Guide and Undocumented Features"](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/) post on wildml, and I am unable to view the output of the `tf.train.batch()` function. The code for storing, loading and processing the input is as follows:

```
sequences = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 1], [1, 2]]
label_sequences = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1]]

def make_example(sequence, labels):
    # The object we return
    ex = tf.train.SequenceExample()
    # A non-sequential feature of our example
    sequence_length = len(sequence)
    ex.context.feature["length"].int64_list.value.append(sequence_length)
    # Feature lists for the two sequential features of our example
    fl_tokens = ex.feature_lists.feature_list["tokens"]
    fl_labels = ex.feature_lists.feature_list["labels"]
    for token, label in zip(sequence, labels):
        fl_tokens.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(token)
        fl_labels.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(label)
    return ex
fname = "/home/someUser/PycharmProjects/someTensors"
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(fname)
for sequence, label_sequence in zip(sequences, label_sequences):
    ex = make_example(sequence, label_sequence)
    print ex
    writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
print("Wrote to {}".format(fname))
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([fname])
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
serialized=serialized_example, context_features=context_features,
sequence_features=sequence_features)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

batched_data = tf.train.batch(tensors=
[context_parsed['length'], sequence_parsed['tokens'],     
sequence_parsed['labels']], batch_size=5, dynamic_pad= True)

batched_context_data = tf.train.batch(tensors= [context_parsed['length']],
batch_size=5, dynamic_pad= True)

batched_tokens_data = tf.train.batch(tensors=
[sequence_parsed['tokens']], batch_size=5, dynamic_pad= True)

batched_labels_data = tf.train.batch(tensors=
[sequence_parsed['labels']], batch_size=5, dynamic_pad= True)
```

Based on the post, it should be possible to view the  output of the batches as follows:

```
res = tf.contrib.learn.run_n({"y": batched_data}, n=1, feed_dict=None)
print("Batch shape: {}".format(res[0]["y"].shape))
print(res[0]["y"])
```

Or as follows for the more specific cases:

```
res = tf.contrib.learn.run_n({"y": batched_context_data}, n=1, feed_dict=None)
print("Batch shape: {}".format(res[0]["y"].shape))
print(res[0]["y"])
```

Unfortunately, TensorFlow takes forever to compute both cases so I end up killing the process. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that this line, with the call to [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners):

```
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
```

...comes before these lines, which contain calls to [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch):

```
batched_data = tf.train.batch(...)

batched_context_data = tf.train.batch(...)

batched_tokens_data = tf.train.batch(...)

batched_labels_data = tf.train.batch(...)
```

If you move the call to `tf.train.start_queue_runners()` **after** the calls to `tf.train.batch()`, then your program should no longer deadlock.

---

Why does this happen? The `tf.train.batch()` function internally creates queues to buffer the data as it is being batched, and in TensorFlow the common way to populate these queues is to create a ["queue runner"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#QueueRunner), which is (usually) a background thread that moves elements into a queue. The `tf.train.start_queue_runners()` function starts background threads for all registered queue runners at the point when it is called, but if it is called before the queue runners are created, then those threads won't be started.